# Complex nested if else statements in Haskell (Performance)

Tags: haskell

If I want to process hundreds of millions of numbers and pass them through an if-else nest like (in procedural):

```
if( n > 0 ){
    if( n > 100 ) {
        if( n > 1000 ) {
           return 1
        }else{
           return 2
        }
    }else{
        if( n > 50 ) {
           return 3
        }else{
           return 4
        }          
}else{
    //more nested else cases
}
```

Procedurally, reaching any of those returns would take exactly 3 comparisons, making sure the average case is optimal if the ranges are set properly (I put random numbers right now, dont mind that). But not sure what would net the best performance on a functional language like Haskell (readability, or ease of typing is not important).

I for example could probably write the if else nest directly, or use guards with the whole if path like:

```
| n > 1000 = 1
| n > 100 = 2
| n > 50 = 3
| n > 0 = 4
| etc
```

But I imagine that while for n>1000 there would only be one comparison, for anything on 0 and etc it would cost more than three.

And a structure like this will probably evaluate n>0 four times, instead of branching:

```
| n > 0, n > 100, n > 1000 = 1
| n > 0, n > 100 = 2
| n > 0, n > 50 = 3
| n > 0 = 4
| etc
```

I could also just use a function, but not sure if functions are inexpensive as a comparison would be.

Comment: This is a very redundant structure.

Comment: `n > 0, n > 100, n > 1000` is equivalent to `n > 1000` but three times the operations.

Comment: Well yeah, that's why Im asking how to do the first code block properly in Haskell. Please remember I want to obtain the equivalent cost of 3 comparisons to reach any return value, no more, no less. The guard I wrote there obv fails.

Comment: [integerLog10](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.3.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Logarithms.html#v:integerLog10), or its slightly faster primed version. You can probably copy-and-paste the source with minor modifications if you're working with a type other than `Integer`.

Comment: tried but the source is huge, and gives me errors, then more errors after solving those, they got out of my haskell skill level, tells me it is hidden if I try to import

Comment: @DanielWagner you should add that suggestion to your answer, and @gia you should accept it. [`intLog10'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.3.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Logarithms.html#v:intLog2-39-) will probably give you the best performance you can feasibly achieve.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Your link *says* `intLog10'`, but the URL is for `intLog2'`. (And there is no `intLog10'`, which is why in my comment I suggested a copy-and-paste job...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, though `if` statements are not particularly liked by Haskellers, there's nothing *wrong* with them. Maybe the best thing would be simply

```
if n > 0
 then if n > 100
       then if n > 1000 then 1 else 2
       else if n > 50 then 3 else 4
 else ...
```

That said, you may be better off delegating the entire comparison stuff to a suitable data type from a library. In fact, these nested comparisons look quite a bit like you're trying to hard-code a [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map).

Comment: Im trying to count the number of digits of millions of numbers without actually spending the cycles to count them, a binary search with if statements sounds optimal to me, I'll benchmark the answers

Comment: @gia Is that your actual goal? You should mention that in the question. Maybe there's a faster way to compute `ceil . log10`.

Comment: ill try but I dont expect log10 to be faster than an if gate, @leftaroundabout benchmark: 1M numbers ~0.04s, 10M ~0.38s 100M ~3.82s (branching ifs), IO takes me 2.89s so its fast although I was hoping for faster (like 0.5s), I also need to improve the IO but I copy pasted some code labeled as fastest..., but maybe I am using it wrong as it may have not have been built for millions of numbers but hundreds of thousands.

Comment: @gia I'm **not** suggesting to compute `log10`, but `ceil . log10` -- the latter might admit a faster algorithm than the trivial composition (I do not know which one, but others might know). Your question is affected by an XY problem. You ask for a vastly more general problem (nested ifs) when all you need might be much, much less. Doing so, you are discarding alternative solutions. If e.g. there were a library efficient function `numberOfDigits` nobody will ever point it to you since you asked for something completely different! -- Hence the XY problem.

Comment: I still want the answer to faster nested ifs alternative if there is one, ceil is not found on hoogle, only ceiling, log10 was not found either

Comment: @gia: `ceil . log10` is most likely faster than nested `if`-s or guards. Consider the cycle penalty for mispredicted branches and Haskell's evaluation laziness. If you're just interested in the number of digits, this really is the way to go. The decision tree is overkill for this problem.

Comment: make a separate answer with code because I havent found neither ceil nor log10 yet

Comment: @gia: both exist in fact under those exact names [in the `cmath` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmath-0.3/docs/Foreign-C-Math-Double.html#v:log10), but I think what chi meant is actually `ceiling . log 10 . fromIntegral`.

Comment: I ran into bugs (eg log 10 = 1 not 2, but thats fixed with +1), then negatives, etc, so I had to use extra operations (guards,addition,etc) anyway. But still ran it with wrong results to see how fast it processes, 1M 0.07s, 10M 0.69s, 100M 6.98s

Comment: The benchmarks aren't really meaningful without seeing the code it benchmarks.

Comment: the code is the same, all that is replaced is the "countbench :: Int -> Int" function contents, the baseline is count returns literal 1 which runs in 2.89s, that makes if-nest last ~1s second, and log 10 last 4x the time. In the case of the tree benchmark I generated the tree in main and passed it down the function chain.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a `Map` and the `lookupLT` operation or similar to implement this. For example:

```
import Data.Map.Strict as M
-- use a lambda to avoid recomputing results on each call
count = \n -> snd <$> M.lookupLT n results where
    results = M.fromAscList [(0,4),(50,3),(100,2),(1000,1)]
```

In ghci:

```
> count 1
Just 4
> count 1001
Just 1
> count (-300)
Nothing
```

If your keys happen to be `Int`s, you can make it slightly faster by swapping in `IntMap` instead.

This should give you something quite close to the optimal number of comparisons -- in the `IntMap` case perhaps even fewer than your nested ifs. I don't know that this approach is necessarily the fastest, but it is quite "literate": readers of this code will not have to decipher a deeply-nested chain of ifs to discover what it does, and modifying the possible results later (if that's needed) will be very simple.

Comment: Due to requiring fast IO I used code that runs a fold on a byte string per character,  I dont know how to add your lambda to the function

Comment: @gia Insufficient information for meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an appropriate decision tree:

```
data Tree n rv = Leaf rv | Node n (Tree n rv) (Tree n rv)
```

Your example would then be encoded as

```
 (Node 0 ({- else nodes -}) -- depending on your other cases
         (Node 100 (Node 50 (Leaf 4) (Leaf 3))
                   (Node 1000 (Leaf 2) (Leaf 1)))
```

(Left and right subtrees correspond to `<` and `>=`. Some tweaking may be necessary if you want to further distinguish between `>` and `==`.)

Walking the tree, you compare your `n` value to the first value in each node, either returning the second value or recursively walking the appropriate subtree.

```
search :: (Eq a, Ord a) => a -> Tree a b ->b
search _ (Leaf x) = x
search x (Node y left right)| x < y = search x left
                                | otherwise = search x right
```

Comment: Thanks, this was fast for lesser millions of numbers 1M ~0.05s, 10M ~0.48s, but a bit slow once more numbers were added 100M ~4.84s (Although if I replace the search function with a plain 1 it still takes 2.89s so there's that bigger IO bottleneck)

Comment: In most cases, deforestation is an optimization, and the deforested version of this answer (and of mine) is exactly the nested ifs that the original question proposes. So it seems unlikely that this will be faster. It could be defensible if it were more maintainable or had some other feature that nested ifs don't; does it have such an alternate feature?